# Nav bar of a website created using Twitterbootstrap not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: css

I have made a website using twitter bootstrap.

Everything is working well on all browsers except Internet Explorer. The Navbar background image does not appear in all versions of Internet Explorer and black background is shown instead.

Apologies for not posting link.

The site link is http://www.dreamsmedia.org/ajmat/index.html

Comment: Did you consider, perhaps, showing some code in your question? Maybe even creating a small [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example?

Comment: Posted it now http://www.dreamsmedia.org/ajmat/index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `bootstrap.css` file, look for the `.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner` selector and delete:

`filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffffffff', GradientType=0);`

And on `.navbar-inner` delete:

`filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffffffff', GradientType=0);`